# Is it possible to get the coordinates only for the highlighted points from an image?

Tags: image-processing

I would like to ask you if it is possible to get the coordinates or a couple of numbers that can give me the positions of the highlights points (selected using HighlightImage function) in an image. I know that there is the possibility to select "get coordinates" by clicking on the image, but I am looking for something that can automate the selection/generation of the points and can remove the image once selected the highlights. 
It would be great if the border could be selected (at least the most external points where the shape 'changes').

Any suggestion will be welcomed.

[image]

Comment: What is a highlighted point?

Comment: I am using the HighlightImage function. This function should select specified regions of interest by dots.

Comment: Right/click on the image and choose "Get coordinates" from the drop/down menu. Then determine the coordinates of the highlighted points.

Comment: Thanks Alexei. I know that there is this possibility, but I would like to take only the highlights without using the tool, but a function.

Comment: As _always_, some example data is necessary here. Please.

Comment: I added an image to explain what I mean with highlighted points. From those points, I would like to get the coordinates, but without using the tool (if it is possible)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you used `HighlightImage`, then you should be able to extract the points directly.

Using the first example in `HighlightImage` (and the more robust code from @kglr):

```
points = Cases[HighlightImage[i, ImageCorners[i, 1, .001, 5]], Point[x_]:>x
(* {{84.5, 75.5}, {116.5, 68.5}, {141.5, 112.5}, {104.5, 86.5}, {154.5, 87.5}, 
    {79.5, 61.5}, {157.5, 78.5}, {163.5, 87.5}, {108.5, 75.5}, {113.5, 44.5},
    {107.5, 39.5}, {94.5, 81.5}, {157.5, 41.5}, {77.5, 67.5}, {147.5, 49.5}, 
    {145.5, 31.5}, {81.5, 48.5}, {167.5, 69.5}, {97.5, 62.5}, {142.5, 96.5},
    {114.5, 59.5}, {48.5, 18.5}, {36.5, 78.5}, {61.5, 110.5}, {92.5, 51.5},
    {74.5, 6.5}, {46.5, 27.5}, {127.5, 15.5}, {133.5, 118.5}, {39.5, 46.5}, 
    {130.5, 3.5}, {33.5, 68.5}, {102.5, 127.5}, {67.5, 21.5}, {138.5, 33.5},
    {128.5, 22.5}, {149.5, 80.5}, {105.5, 112.5}, {146.5, 103.5}, {72.5, 105.5},
    {82.5, 99.5}, {87.5, 124.5}, {163.5, 34.5}, {87.5, 108.5}, {139.5, 19.5}, 
    {61.5, 32.5}, {112.5, 3.5}, {75.5, 121.5}, {132.5, 107.5}, {75.5, 114.5}, 
    {111.5, 116.5}, {53.5, 25.5}, {87.5, 44.5}, {74.5, 87.5}, {149.5, 73.5}, 
    {154.5, 20.5}, {93.5, 107.5}, {41.5, 64.5}, {44.5, 96.5}, {112.5, 14.5},
    {82.5, 1.5}, {33.5, 59.5}, {56.5, 16.5}, {69.5, 50.5}, {82.5, 13.5},
    {91.5, 27.5}, {67.5, 95.5}, {50.5, 38.5}, {55.5, 101.5}, {63.5, 4.5}, 
    {62.5, 60.5}, {117.5, 123.5}, {62.5, 44.5}, {81.5, 23.5}, {61.5, 66.5},
    {122.5, 53.5}} *)

Show[i, ListPlot[points, PlotStyle -> Red]]
```

[image: Points in image]

Comment: slightly shorter: `points=Cases[HighlightImage[i, ImageCorners[i, 1, .001, 5]], Point[x_]:>x, All][[1]];`

Comment: @kglr Thanks!  I have some mental block about understanding `Cases` and `patterns` no matter how many times I read the documentation so I end up attempting figuring out what `Part` it is I'm trying to grab.

Comment: Thank you to both! Wow! Finally it works! I have a question for you, if I may ask: if the number of points that I wanted to use was fixed, how could I change the HighlightImage function? I thought using ImageCorners[i, MaxFeatures -> 30] but it is wrong

Comment: You'll need to ask that as a separate specific question.  I have no idea about that.

Comment: Ok. Thanks JimB