# Is it possible to select a number of points to highlight points in an image?

Tags: image-processing

I would like to ask you how I can fix a number of points to show in a picture. 
In the previous post ([Is it possible to get the coordinates only for the highlighted points from an image?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/206665/is-it-possible-to-get-the-coordinates-only-for-the-highlighted-points-from-an-im/206683#206683)), JimB suggested a good solution to determine the contour of the image and get the coordinates of those points. It would be interesting to know if there is a way to select a certain number of points that can "draw" the image (for example, 10). 
I tried using MaxFeatures ->10 in the ImageCorners, but it randomly selects the points.

[image]

Thank you for all the help you will provide it.

Comment: You could try to play around with the radius and threshold parameters of `ImageCorners` to reduce the number of points in a more meaningful way. Of course, this is an indirect approach since you can't set the maximum number of points, but it should be better than randomly selecting a subset.

Comment: Thanks Lukas. I tried what you suggested, but the result is very (very) bad. I cannot find a good image by dots by reducing the number or fixing it. At least, I would like to have dots in the main parts of the figures, just to 'see' the shape of the image using a few dots.